# Сохранение результата в SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Есть текстовое поле text1, в которое передается результат теста (число с точкой). 
При выходе из активити результат теста сохраняется с помощью метода saveText()

```
void saveText() {
ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putString(TEST_Del_L, text1.getText().toString());
    …
    ed.apply();}
```

При старте активити с помощью метода loadText() загружается результат теста в поле text1

```
sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref_Del", MODE_PRIVATE);

del_L=sPref.getString(TEST_Del_L, null);
del_N=sPref.getString(TEST_Del_N, null);
del_S=sPref.getString(TEST_Del_S,null);

void loadText() {
    if (del_L==null && del_N==null && del_S==null
 ){
        text1.setText("");
        text2.setText("");
        text3.setText("");
            }else {
        text1.setText(del_L);
        float del_L_fl = Float.parseFloat(del_L);
        del_L_fl = del_L_fl/2;
        ratingBar_pr.setRating(del_L_fl);
…}
```

При изначально пустом значении поля text1 программа при открытии активити выдает ошибку. А если тест был пройден, то все работает хорошо. В чем ошибка?

Код ошибки:

```
03-08 18:57:11.875 9240-9240/ru.android.myschool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.android.myschool/ru.android.myschool.Activity_all_tests}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
at ru.android.myschool.Activity_all_tests.loadText(Activity_all_tests.java:79)
at ru.android.myschool.Activity_all_tests.onCreate(Activity_all_tests.java:66)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь несколько моментов:

1.При получении `sPref.getString(TEST_Del_S, null);` второй параметр это default значение если строка не будет получена. Есть смысл написать `del_S=sPref.getString(TEST_Del_S, "");` или логику. Тогда избавитесь от лишнего кода, в методе loadText() да и код станет читабельный. И не будете в худшем случае выводить null, что может привести к ошибке.

2.Второй && это 'и', вы видимо хотели поставить || 'или', чтоб избежать попадания null, в выводе. Но всё же предпочтения к первому варианту.

3.Если оставить String "", то тогда здесь `float del_L_fl = Float.parseFloat(del_L);` будет выдавать ошибку формата, так как он из стринга будет ждать число. Есть смысл, заменить default value при получении на `"0"`

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку при запуске активити, ссылается на строчки  `float del_L_fl = Float.parseFloat(del_L);` и `loadText()`, который стартует в методе oncreate.

Comment: тогда ошибочку в студию)

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: все, исправила на del_S=sPref.getString(TEST_Del_S, "0.0"); и все заработало

Comment: Да, вижу. нельзя распарсить "" такой String в float. Попробуйте просто поставить в default value где я писал, значение типа "0", вместе написали. Да всё верно))))